# Qt Creator Error ":-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'glu32.lib'"

Tags: c++, qt

I downloaded the [Qt Creator version 5.4.1.](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/)

I created a Qt widget console project, and made a simple push button and label gui, here's the pro code :

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Test1 TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

QMAKE_LIBDIR += "glu32_location"
```

I tried to add `QMAKE_LIBDIR += "glu32_location"`, but it still doesn't work, and I still get the same error. Did I do anything wrong?

I just install the installer and the software, do I need to download a compiler? I used Visual Studio 13 before trying Qt.

Comment: If you use VC 2013 Express/community you'll need to install the Windows SDK as well. glu32.lib is provided with WinSDK (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk)